# Should I even continue trying to import a module from the parent package?

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-packaging, pipenv

After failing for hours attempting to import a module from the parent package, I'm asking myself:

Is *importing a parent package module into a subpackage module* even good practice or is this attempt not recommended at all?

PS: I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143/1172907) to no avail. Even after `pipenv install -e .`,  `import parent` in subpackage fails regardless the count of dots of prefix e.g. `import .parent | ..parent`

PPS: the `sys` hack in every subpackage smells somehow anti-DRY

Comment: You should always be able to use absolute imports. If you have code in `parent.child`, you should be able to `import parent` (as should any other Python code that wants to use the `parent` module). If that's not working, you would need to update your question to show us your code, the organization of your project, and how exactly you're running things.